# setting raspberry pi zero to automatically power on after power failure

Tags: power, pi-zero-w, remote, settings, current

I'm planning to buy a Raspberry Pi Zero W to remotelly wake on my desktop pc. To do this task I need that the raspberry always stays awake; is there a way to set the raspberry automatically wake on after a power failure (such as a black out)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> is there a way to set the raspberry automatically wake on after a power failure (such as a black out)?

Since there is no power button this will happen automatically. When you plug a Pi in, it turns on, so the same thing will happen when the power comes back.

Beware that cutting the power arbitrarily (such as in a black out) risks filesystem corruption.<sup>1</sup>  This probably won't create a problem for you (unless you have a dozen black outs a day, etc.) but you should be aware of it in case it fails to reboot properly.

Because of that risk when you intend to unplug the Pi make sure to *properly shut down the operating system first*.  This should significantly mitigate again the chance of corruption.

---

1. This is no different from a normal computer, except that they usually have physical buttons which when pushed shut down the OS then cut the power.  If you pull the cord instead, you risk filesystem corruption on a desktop.